# Android arrayAdapter and BaseAdapter getContext ? why getContext works on array adapter but not on base adapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

Why does the getContext() method works on ArrayAdapter inside getView method.

```
convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
```

why the same code does work on BaseAdapter ?

Code Class extending ArrayAdapter ?

```
package com.example.manis.mylist3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Manis on 8/6/2016.
 */

public class NoteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    public NoteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Note> notes) {
        super(context, 0 ,notes);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      //  Log.v("adapter","called"+position);
        Note note = (Note) getItem(position);

        if(convertView==null){
           // Log.v("noteAdapter","ConvertView was null");
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
        }
        TextView noteTitle= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowTitle);
        TextView noteSubText= (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowSubText);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowImg);

        noteTitle.setText(note.getTitle());
        noteSubText.setText(note.getSubtext());
        img.setImageResource(note.getAssociatedDrawable());

        return convertView;
    }


}
```

Code for NoteBaseAdapter Class Extending BaseAdapter

```
package com.example.manis.mylist3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class NoteBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Note> notes;
    Context context;
    public NoteBaseAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Note> notes)
    {
        this.context=c;
        this.notes=notes;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return notes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return notes.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

//error
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);

    }
}
```

Comment: Because ArrayAdapter has a `getContext` method but `BaseAdapter` doesn't.  Just make one yourself and return `context` or just use `context` directly.

Comment: why didnt baseadapter has getcontext method any reason ? Wouldn't it have been more helpful ? or Because it is more of the abstract class ?

Comment: It's more of an abstract class.  It's meant to provide the base level of methods you'll need to implement an Adapter. Not every adapter may need a Context so to make it leaner they just leave it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the `ArrayAdapter` extends `BaseAdapter` and has a `context` variable in its constructor which is saved and can be accessed using `getContext()`. Whereas, `BaseAdapter` has an empty constructor. You don't provide one to it, so you can't get it from the base class. If you need one, make your own constructor like the `ArrayAdapter` class did and save your `context` there.